# C# Switch type for multiple Dictionary types

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I want to add Switch case based on type of input parameter.
E.g. My input parameter can be of type double, Dictionary<int, string>, Dictionary<decimal, bool>

For that I have added below switch case which calls correctly for both Dictionary types mentioned above but from there i have to call another function which will log that Dictionary. For that function i have taken input as Dictionary<object, object> so that it can accept both types of dictionary but it is unable to cast above dictionary types to  Dictionary<object, object>

Below is my complete code

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Dictionary < int, string > dict = new Dictionary < int, string > () {
        {
            1,
            "One"
        }, {
            2,
            "Two"
        }
    };
    Dictionary < decimal, bool > dict2 = new Dictionary < decimal, bool > () {
        {
            1,
            true
        }, {
            2,
            false
        }
    };
    Double doubleObj = 100.2;

    HandleLogging(doubleObj);
    HandleLogging(dict);
    HandleLogging(dict2);
}

private static void HandleLogging(Object obj) {
    switch (obj) {
    case double _:
        Console.WriteLine($"Dobule data type ..");
        break;

    case Dictionary < int, string > _:
    case Dictionary < decimal, bool > _:
        // case object dictType2 when dictType2 == typeof(Dictionary<decimal, bool>):

        //case Dictionary<object, object> d:
        Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary data type..");
        HandleDictionary((Dictionary < object, object > ) obj);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("unknown type");
        break;
    }
}

private static void HandleDictionary(Dictionary < object, object > existingDictionary) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dictionary object : {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existingDictionary)));
}
```

Comment: what is a point of a common method handling multiple types when you switch on those types anyway? Justz call the appropriate overload within your `Main`-method, then you don't need to switch at all.

Comment: FYI there is the non generic `IDictionary` interface, which seems to be what you are looking for | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary

Comment: Here a simple sample code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKn8Ew

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain - Regarding your question, this is just sample code which i have created to simulate my usecase, my actual method accepts generic parameter T and it is not know at compile time and i might need to add different types in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pure "how do I do it" point of view (without discussing why and is it a good practice in general case) - [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) implements `IDictionary` (which is non-generic version of dictionary) so you can match against it:

```cs
case IDictionary _:
   Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary data type..");
   Console.WriteLine("Dictionary object : {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
   break;
```

Comment: Thank you @"Guru Stron" and "Rand Random" for your responses.. Yes IDictionary did help me here.   So i modified both case stament as  `"case IDictionary _:"` and another method parameter as `private static void HandleDictionary(IDictionary existingDictionary)`